# Get Sonarqube report against specific code base

Tags: sonarqube

I have very old application, which doesn't meet code coverage and code quality. Having like 20% code coverage and 500+ code smells. Now for year 2018 I want track code quality.

To track this I think of below one solution,
Every time generate sonarqube report against specific version so that can be able to get idea about code quality in new bugs, new code smells section. I will be able to track code quality on newly added code in 2018.  How can I achieve this in sonarquebe... or any other better suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube is tailor-made to help you focus on the quality of new code, or code [in the leak period](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Fixing+the+Water+Leak). New code metrics appear on the project front page in the yellow-highlighted section on the right of the page, and the default Quality Gate focuses on new code as well.